# Loading data into a FlowControl as you scroll - C#

Tags: c#, flow-control

I'm creating a program which displays product information and I want it to have two display modes, table view and then a scrollable control view with images etc.

I have all my product info loaded into a data table and want to use this to populate my FlowControl however, there is too much data and it times out.

Is there a method which can be used to load the data as the Flow is scrolled?

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt_prods.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Product flowProd = new Product();
    flowProd.Controls["lbl_product"].Text = dt_prods.Rows[i]["product"].ToString();
    flow_products.Controls.Add(flowProd);
}
```

Above is my code that passes the data to the FlowControl currently.

Comment: How many are we talking about?

Comment: Around 2000 products, each with an image.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  No user is going to take the time to scroll through two thousand product images to find the one he's interested in.  Make your UI usable and you'll automatically solve this problem as well.

Comment: The products will be filterable, so I guess I could load the flowControl after the filtering is applied?

Comment: The idea is that it will load them all, and then filtering will be faster etc. So get all the loading done in one go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some  pagination instead for example your load 25 objects on the start of the application to the panel and then you create buttons dynamically that shows different data  on your panel when you click on different buttons I think you can make it it's very easy

Comment: Ahh, I like this idea. So I load 25, then when an arrow is clicked it loads the next 25 and displays these!